# Converting text to singular Ascii number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, ascii

I want to convert the text "Hello world" to a single Ascii number. Obviously my code below is just going to alert each Ascii value individually, but I want them be alerted all side by side like: 72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100

```
var input = "Hello world"

var arr = input.split('')

for(var i =0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    var number = arr[i].charCodeAt(0);
    alert(number)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually alerting each time you execute the loop. Just change your code to:

```
var input = "Hello world"

var arr = input.split('')
var number="";
for(var i =0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    number = number + " " + arr[i].charCodeAt(0);

}
alert(number);
```